# Find g and C so that $\int_0^3f(x)dx= C*\int_a^bg(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying for n exam and don't have solutions for this problem:

Let $f:[0,3] \to R $, so that

$\int_0^3f(x)dx$ exists.

Find a function g and a constant C so that

$\int_0^3f(x)dx= C*\int_a^bg(x)dx$.

g shall depend only on f and C on a and b.

I think I have to solve this by substituting, but am not sure.
Thanks for any hint!

Comment: It isn't immediately visible to me why $g (x) $ can't be $f (x)/C $.

Comment: @Rohan: The limits of integration are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase Fred to match the wording of your problem: let (constant) $ g(x) = \int_0^3{f(t)\,dt} $ and $ C = \frac{1}{b-a} $.  Then $$ C\int_a^b{g(x)\,dx} = \frac{1}{b-a}\cdot(b-a)\cdot\int_0^3{f(t)\,dt}=\int_0^3{f(t)\,dt} $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Introduce a new variable $u$ such that $x=\frac{3}{b-a}\cdot u + \frac{3a}{a-b}$